# What's the Viz tool in neo4j console?

Tags: console, neo4j, visualization

I just found the neo4j console has a very nice Viz effect. Could anyone tell me how it is implemented? Is it based on D3j, sigma.js or one of other js based visualization tools?

And is that possible to just use this Viz tool in my program instead of using the whole console? Thanks very much!

Comment: As we spec out the API for the visualization component, would you mind sharing your use case and any feature requests? Please send any thoughts to andreas@neotechnology.com

Comment: Yes. I would like to do that. I am still learning D3J and trying to use it with Neo4j in my project, will figure out some of my critical needs in future. Really cool product, thanks for your answer and work!

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j Browser uses D3js and renders as an SVG. It isn't (yet) available as a separate component, but we are working towards that.

Cheers,
Andreas